# Get Parse _User's objectId in beforeSave function in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Scenario is when new users add or signup an object of that user must be created in 'userPrivileges' class with some default values,

I am using below code for that

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response)
{
  if(request.object.isNew())
  {
    var userPrivilege = Parse.Object.extend("userPrivileges");
    var userPriv = new userPrivilege();
    userPriv.set("userType","Normal");
    userPriv.set("userID",request.object.id);
    userPriv.set("submitQus",true);
    userPriv.save();
    response.success();
  }
  else
  {
    response.success();
  }
});
```

The issue is object added to userPrivileges but doest not get User's objectId which I am assigning to 'userPrivileges' userID.. where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get `objectID` in `beforeSave` hook if the object `isNew()` because the object is not in the database yet, ergo doesn't have an id. You should use `afterSave` hook and `existed()` instead.

Comment: Thank you I should have think that :D

Comment: You gave me vote up but not marked the answer as accepted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work thanks in advance